# Filter nested Object property uisng @JsonFilter

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have gone through many StackOverflow's questions and github's issues, but didn't get the solution of my problem.
I have class as follow :

```
@JsonFilter("apiFilter")
Class Employee{
    String id,
    String name;
    Address address,
}
@JsonFilter("apiFilter")
Class Address{
    String id,
    String city,
    String state,
    String country,
}
```

I want to filter the properties of Employee and its nested object Address properties using `@JosnFilter` while returning the response of API, where I am able to filter the properties of Employee with below set of codes

```
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter propertyFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("name", "address");
        
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("apiFilter", propertyFilter).setFailOnUnknownId(false);
```

But I need to filter the properties of nested object also using **dot(.)** For example `"address.city"` and
`"address.state"` will be passed in `filterOutAllExcept("address.state","address.city")` . I could not use a different filter for address as I need to filter property based on object reference dot(.) its properties like `address.state`

I have gone through these github issues but there is no recent update on the support of nested object properties by jackson.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/230

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1040

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17187

Any suggestion would be a great help.. Thanks.